# Why won't this while loop, loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program, that goes randomly through a stack of cards for 'i' amount of decks. However my while loop seems to stop after 1 run? How come it won't loop?

```
cards = ['Two of Hearts', 'Two of Diamonds', 'Two of Spades', 'Two of Clubs', 'Three of Hearts', 'Three of Diamonds', 'Three of Spades', 'Three of Clubs', 'Four of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds', 'Four of Spades', 'Four of Clubs', 'Five of Hearts', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Five of Spades', 'Five of Clubs', 'Six of Hearts', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Six of Spades', 'Six of Clubs', 'Seven of Hearts', 'Seven of Diamonds', 'Seven of Spades', 'Seven of Clubs', 'Eight of Hearts', 'Eight of Diamonds', 'Eight of Spades', 'Eight of Clubs', 'Nine of Hearts', 'Nine of Diamonds', 'Nine of Spades', 'Nine of Clubs', 'Ten of Hearts', 'Ten of Diamonds', 'Ten of Spades', 'Ten of Clubs', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs']

i = 0

while i <= 5:
    cardsTemp = cards
    for n in cardsTemp:
        card = random.randint(1,len(cardsTemp)) - 1
        print(cardsTemp[card])
        print('cardsTempt len: ' + str(len(cardsTemp)))
        cardsTemp.remove(cardsTemp[card])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Be careful with `cardsTemp = cards`: if you change `cardsTemp`, you'll also change `cards`. Try with `cardsTemp = cards[:]` instead, that makes a proper copy of `cards`.

Comment: Also consider using one of `random.choice`, `random.choices`, `random.shuffle` or `random.sample`, just as needed.

Comment: I seem to see your program looping and incrementing `i` until `i` is `5`.

Comment: @quamrana -- yes, but the deck size is reduced in half each time through the while loop (i.e. not the full deck each time).

Comment: @DarrylG -- yes, but the OP states: `"while loop seems to stop after 1 run"` which doesn't happen.

Comment: @quamrana --yes, the posted description of the issue is confusing.

Comment: @Keveran: Is there some other problem you have with your code? The `while` loop doesn't seem to be the actual problem.

Comment: As written, the output of 5 `while`-loop iterations with progressively smaller `for` loops inside is indistinguishable from a single `while`-loop iteration with a `for` loop that iterates over the entire deck. Add `print(i)` as the first line of the `while` loop and you'll see that the `while` loop does, in fact, iterate 5 times.

Comment: If you use `cardsTemp = cards[:]`, you'll get what you seem to expect: 5 independent iterations over the entire deck, which brings us back to [9769953's original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371594/why-wont-this-while-loop-loop/71371629?noredirect=1#comment126153691_71371594).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much more easily using `for` loops. This is what the `range()` function is for:

```py
import random

cards = ['Two of Hearts', 'Two of Diamonds', 'Two of Spades', 'Two of Clubs', 'Three of Hearts', 'Three of Diamonds', 'Three of Spades', 'Three of Clubs', 'Four of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds', 'Four of Spades', 'Four of Clubs', 'Five of Hearts', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Five of Spades', 'Five of Clubs', 'Six of Hearts', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Six of Spades', 'Six of Clubs', 'Seven of Hearts', 'Seven of Diamonds', 'Seven of Spades', 'Seven of Clubs', 'Eight of Hearts', 'Eight of Diamonds', 'Eight of Spades', 'Eight of Clubs', 'Nine of Hearts', 'Nine of Diamonds', 'Nine of Spades', 'Nine of Clubs', 'Ten of Hearts', 'Ten of Diamonds', 'Ten of Spades', 'Ten of Clubs', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs']

for i in range(5):
    print('\n   LOOP {}'.format(i))

    cardsTemp = cards[:]
    for n in range(len(cards)):
        card = random.randint(1,len(cardsTemp)) - 1
        print(cardsTemp[card])
        print('cardsTempt len: ' + str(len(cardsTemp)))
        cardsTemp.remove(cardsTemp[card])
```

Comment: This worked great! I'm still learning python.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the orignal cards into cards temp inside the while loop.

```py
while i <= 5:
    cardsTemp = cards.copy()
    for n in cardsTemp.copy():
        card = random.randint(1,len(cardsTemp)) - 1
        print(cardsTemp[card])
        print('cardsTempt len: ' + str(len(cardsTemp)))
        cardsTemp.remove(cardsTemp[card])
    i += 1
```

Comment: This did work - however when doing this, the for loop stopped when len(cardsTemp) reached 27

Comment: But is that right or wrong? What do you expect to achieve with your code?

Comment: I expected it to go through the whole deck of cards, then repeat for the second deck (loop)

Comment: You mean to want to remove all 52 cards from the deck 5 times over, each starting with a new copy of the deck?

Comment: Check I have updated the code, now it runs throughout the deck and doesn't stop at 27

Answer (score 0):

My fault was that I didn't copy the cards list into the cardsTemp. When doing this, it perfectly looped, however the for loop stopped after 25 cards for some reason. I fixed this by making a while loop within the while loop.

This worked for me. Thanks for the answers!

```
cards = ['Two of Hearts', 'Two of Diamonds', 'Two of Spades', 'Two of Clubs', 'Three of Hearts', 'Three of Diamonds', 'Three of Spades', 'Three of Clubs', 'Four of Hearts', 'Four of Diamonds', 'Four of Spades', 'Four of Clubs', 'Five of Hearts', 'Five of Diamonds', 'Five of Spades', 'Five of Clubs', 'Six of Hearts', 'Six of Diamonds', 'Six of Spades', 'Six of Clubs', 'Seven of Hearts', 'Seven of Diamonds', 'Seven of Spades', 'Seven of Clubs', 'Eight of Hearts', 'Eight of Diamonds', 'Eight of Spades', 'Eight of Clubs', 'Nine of Hearts', 'Nine of Diamonds', 'Nine of Spades', 'Nine of Clubs', 'Ten of Hearts', 'Ten of Diamonds', 'Ten of Spades', 'Ten of Clubs', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs']

i = 0

while i <= 1:
    print('\n   LOOP {}'.format(i))

    cardsTemp = cards.copy()
    n = 0

    while n < len(cardsTemp):
        card = random.randint(1,len(cardsTemp)) - 1
        print(cardsTemp[card])
        print('cardsTempt len: ' + str(len(cardsTemp)))
        cardsTemp.remove(cardsTemp[card])

    i += 1
```

Comment: Check my answer, without using another while loop it can be fixed.